# convergence in probability confusion

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm confused by the definition of convergence in probability (as discussed in [Types of convergence in probability confusion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227387/types-of-convergence-in-probability-confusion)).

We have a sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots$ of random variables, and a random variable $X$. My understanding is that convergence in probability is defined as, for all $\epsilon > 0$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

$$ \mathbb{P} \left[ | X_n - X | \geq \epsilon \right] \rightarrow 0, $$

where the probability is defined as

$$ \mathbb{P} \left[ | X_n - X | \geq \epsilon \right] := \mathbb{P} \left( \omega \in \Omega | X_n (\omega) - X (\omega) \right). $$

So then doesn't convergence in probability depend on the sample space $\Omega$ and the probability function?

Scenario 1. Dependence on sample space:  let each $X_i$ be the result of a coin flip ($1$ if heads, else $0$). Let $X$ be the result of a die roll ($1$ if even, $0$ if odd). So then the $X_i$ don't converge to $X$.

Scenario 2. Dependence on probability function:  let each $X_i$ and $X$ be the result of a coin flip ($1$ if heads, else $0$). Let $X'$ be the result of a coin flip ($0$ if heads, else $1$). Then the $X_i$ converge to $X$, but not to $X'$.

If the above are true, then it seems that we can't answer questions like problem 1 of https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/1aea12bd54eb19c821501f730cc247d9_MIT18_650F16_PSet1.pdf without information about the sample space and probability function.

What am I missing? Am I just overthinking?

Comment: You seem pretty confused about the definition of a random variable.  A random variable is by definition a function on the sample space.  So it doesn't even make sense to talk about a random variable without already having a sample space.

Comment: Problem 1 does not *define* specific random variables.  Instead, it *supposes* you have random variables that satisfy the given properties.  A priori, this is not necessarily enough information to answer the question (since you do not know exactly what these random variables are) but it turns out that the answer is the same for all such random variables.

Comment: I see, thanks @EricWofsey. If I'm understanding correctly, information about the PDF alone can only be used to show that we don't have convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that something fishy is going on with question 1. Let us examine the definition of convergence in probability. It says that given $\varepsilon >0$, and a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$, $X_n\to X$ in probability means $\mathbb P(\lvert X_n-X\rvert \geq \varepsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. So you are correct that $X_n$ and $X$ all need to be defined on the same probability space.

However, maybe this definition is a little restrictive. Actually, what if we assume that $X_n$ is a random variable on $(\Omega_n,\mathcal F_n,\mathbb P_n)$ and that $X$ is a random variable on $(\Omega_n,\mathcal F_n,\mathbb P_n)$ for every $n$. Then we can generalize the definition as
needing $\mathbb P_n(\omega\in \Omega_n:\lvert X_n-X\rvert \geq \varepsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. The issue is that it may not always be possible for such an $X$ to exist. But there is a special case when it does. If $X$ is almost surely constant, then we can clearly do so. In fact, if $X$ is almost surely constant, then convergence in distribution and convergence in probability are equivalent and it is common to denote both as $X_n\Rightarrow c$.

Comment: I should remark that perhaps it is implicit in problem 1 that $X_n$ are all defined on the same probability space, since the notation is $\mathbb P$ and not $\mathbb P_n$. However, the issue of whether we can actually have an $X$ on the same sample space still remains, but as stated above, it's certainly possible if $X$ is a.s. constant.